# Escaping zero length characters in bash

Tags: bash, colors

Based on [Bash color how-to](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html) I've tried to output a string in grey:

```
printf " \[\033[1;30m\]foo\[\033[0m\]"
```

What I get out though is: `\[\]foo\[\]`

According to the link above any zero width characters need to be surrounded by `\[` and `\]` but it seems those characters are being output.

Any idea how to ensure the `\[` is handled correctly?

Comment: I *think* `\[\]` is a `$PS1`-specific thing.

Comment: The escape codes, and the requirement to use them, are specific to the  prompt string. `printf` certainly doesn't care about the visible length of the  string it prints.

Comment: @Biffen I think you are right. My mistake, I didn't understand that.

Comment: The escape codes are not specific to PS1; they are standard ANSI codes interpreted by the terminal. `\[` and `\]` *are* specific to the prompt though; the shell uses them to determine the displayed length of the prompt. Specifically, they are used to send yet another pair of control characters (`\001` and `\002`, I think) to the `readline` library to indicate characters that don't appear on screen, to facilitate correct cursor positioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @chepner mentioned in his comment: the `\[` sequences are used by some utilities, including PS1, to represent the `\001` and `\002` control codes:

`\[` => `\x01` or `\001`

`\]` => `\x02` or `\002`

printf and echo don't do this translation from `\[` to `\001`.

So the solution was to do the conversion myself. Instead of wrapping zero length characters in `\[`:

```
echo "\[\033[1;30m\]foo\[\033[0m\]"
```

which would output `\[foo\]`

I instead output the actual control code:

```
echo "\x01\033[1;30m\x02foo\x01\033[0m\x02"
```

which outputs `foo` on both PS1 printf and echo.

For a concrete example see [this commit on git-radar.](https://github.com/michaeldfallen/git-radar/commit/11e8ad4bdce9979eb871635bf455213788de5e05)

Answer (score -1):

```
printf "\033[1;30mfoo\033[0m"
```

is enough. `\033[` (`ESC[`) starts the ANSI escape codes and `m` closes them.